# Issue on tvOS - Request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: ServiceUnavailable

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, tvos

I am developing a SDK for iOS, macOS and tvOS. This SDK uses the Apple keychain to store some sensitive information. I have some unit tests to cover the keychain access. Since the unit tests require keychain access I need to create a dummy app to be associated them. Otherwise I can't access the keychain. The unit tests run fine on both iOS and macOS but on tvOS I get the following error:

"The request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: ServiceUnavailable ("PBD] Process 'companyname.appname' is not running; transaction started, is running, was not interrupted, and did not fail, with errors: ()."

Does anybody know the origin of this error?

Comment: I see similar issue, but only if I try to execute the tests from command line. When started from Xcode they work fine.